# How can I open a .snappy.parquet file in python?

Tags: python, parquet, snappy

How can I open a .snappy.parquet file in python 3.5? So far, I used this code:

```
import numpy
import pyarrow

filename = "/Users/T/Desktop/data.snappy.parquet" 
df = pyarrow.parquet.read_table(filename).to_pandas()
```

But, it gives this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'compat'
```

P.S. I installed pyarrow this way:

```
pip install pyarrow
```

Answer (score 8):

I have got the same issue and managed to solve it by following the solutio proposed in https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/366 solution.

1) install python-snappy by using conda install (for some reason with pip install, I couldn't download it)

2) Add the snappy_decompress function.

```
from fastparquet import ParquetFile
import snappy
def snappy_decompress(data, uncompressed_size):
    return snappy.decompress(data)
pf = ParquetFile('filename') # filename includes .snappy.parquet extension
dff=pf.to_pandas()
```

Comment: `Add the snappy_decompress function` → why? The `pf = ParquetFile('filename')` and `dff=pf.to_pandas()` lines are doing all magic by itself. `import snappy` and `snappy_decompress` function is doing nothing in this example.

Answer (score 6):

You can use pandas to read snppay.parquet files into a python pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
filename = "/Users/T/Desktop/data.snappy.parquet"
df = pd.read_parquet(filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error `AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'compat'` is sadly a bit misleading. To execute the `to_pandas()` function on a `pyarrow.Table` instance you need pandas installed. The above error is a sympton of the missing requirement.

pandas is a not a hard requirement of `pyarrow` as most of its functionality is usable with just Python built-ins and NumPy. Thus users of `pyarrow` which include pandas can work with it without needing to have pandas pre-installed.