# Trying to import Koalas in Spark

Tags: python, pip, pyarrow

After pip installing koalas,  I tried to import it using the code below and it returns the error message far below.    Any direction on how to fix this?

### `import databricks.koalas as ks`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-9015139547840077087.py", line 331, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/a-4.2.0-py-3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/databricks/koalas/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import pyarrow
  File "/usr/lib/a-4.2.0-py-3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pyarrow.compat as compat
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'compat'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-9015139547840077087.py", line 333, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-9015139547840077087.py", line 331, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/a-4.2.0-py-3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/databricks/koalas/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import pyarrow
  File "/usr/lib/a-4.2.0-py-3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pyarrow.compat as compat
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'compat'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I open a .snappy.parquet file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656972/how-can-i-open-a-snappy-parquet-file-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+module+%27pyarrow%27+has+no+attribute+%27compat%27

Comment: what is your `pyarrow` version?